# Animate accordion plugin with auto height

Tags: javascript, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using a very lightweight plugin for an accordion which is great but I can't get it to animate without a fixed height.

I initially tried the usual transitions before realising they did not work with auto height

I tried modifying some JS I found but this did not work

```
var headers = document.querySelectorAll('.aab__accordion_head');

for (var i=0; i<headers.length; i++) {
  headers[i].addEventListener('click', toggleDisplay);
}

function toggleDisplay() {
  if (this.parentNode.classList.contains('aab__accordion_body--show')) {
    var currentlyDisplayed = document.querySelectorAll('.aab__accordion_body--show');
    for (var e=0; e<currentlyDisplayed.length; e++) {
      currentlyDisplayed[e].classList.remove('aab__accordion_body--show');
    } 
  } else {
    this.closest('.aab__accordion_body').classList.add('aab__accordion_body--show');
  }
}
```

I also tried a suggestion of using ScaleY like this

```
.wp-block-aab-accordion-block .aab__accordion_body {
    transform: scaleY(0);
    display: 
    transition: scale 300ms ease-in-out !important; 

}


.wp-block-aab-accordion-block .aab__accordion_body.aab__accordion_body--show {
    transform: scaleY(1);
    transition: scale 300ms ease-in-out !important; 
}
```

But this still reserves the space where it should be and doesn't work.

I've tried this too but with no luck

```
.aab__accordion_container  {
    display: grid !important;
}

.aab__accordion_head:hover + .aab__accordion_body--show {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: column !important;
}

.aab__accordion_container p {
    flex-basis: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

I will actually have Gutenberg blocks in there too but I just thought i would test to see if I could get the

to show

I wold post all the other code but I'm finding it difficult as I didn't write it.

Essentially the basic structure for
1 - Each accordion container
2- The heading container that always shows
3 - The heading that you click
4 - The content is:

```
<div class=".aab__accordion_container">
   <div class=".aab__accordion_head">
      <div class=".aab__accordion_heading .aab_right_icon">
        <h4>the heading</h4>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class=".aab__accordion_body">
      The content
    </div>
</div>
```

An active accordion gets the class

```
.aab__accordion_body--show
```

added to

```
.aab__accordion_body
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

*********EDIT*********

So I managed to get it working by editing this JS

```
// jQuery accordion
;(function($){
    $( ".wp-block-aab-accordion-block" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      active : 'none',
      header: ".aab__accordion_head",
      heightStyle: "content",
      activate: function( event, ui ) {
        if(!$.isEmptyObject(ui.newHeader.offset())) {
          if ($(window).width() > 767) {
            $('html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)').animate({ scrollTop: ui.newHeader.offset().top -180 }, 'slow');
          }
          else {
            $('html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)').animate({ scrollTop: ui.newHeader.offset().top -50 }, 'slow');
          }
        }
      }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Credit to this website
https://titus-design.com/custom-accordion-gutenberg-block-using-advanced-custom-fields/

I just have to work out how to override the plugin JS now...

Answer (score 0):

The only issue with transitioning `scaleY` is that the element will still take up it's full height in the flow of elements, leaving a space where you don't want it.

Transitioning to a `height: auto` is not possible with CSS (as I'm sure you know) but there is a hacky workaround I have used in the past for such situations.

Make use of the `max-height` property.  You will have to set a fixed value on the max-height, but the element will still only have a height of its content if you set `max-height` to a value larger than you expect the largest element to be.

Something like this:

```
.wp-block-aab-accordion-block .aab__accordion_body {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 300ms ease-in-out !important; 
}


.wp-block-aab-accordion-block .aab__accordion_body.aab__accordion_body--show {
    max-height: 1000px;
}
```

Notice, that you only need the transition property on the base class, and you only need to modify the `max-height` on the added class.

As a note, your implementation of `scaleY` will not work because of your transition property.  If you want to use scaleY, change it to be like this:

```
.wp-block-aab-accordion-block .aab__accordion_body {
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out !important; 
}


.wp-block-aab-accordion-block .aab__accordion_body.aab__accordion_body--show {
    transform: scaleY(1); 
}
```

The `transition` is on `transform`, not on `scale`.  `scaleY` is the type of transform, but you can only apply `transition` on the property itself, not its values.

Comment: As a further note, don't try to transition from `display: none`.  This will never do what you want it to do.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much

So I tried both solutions and yes - I couldn't transition from display none

The first actually works well except that the close toggle does not work properly.

The second still reserves a space which you can see now at the link - though the transition itself is nice

Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  My only suggestion with the close toggle, is to double check that the class name you are removing is actually being removed.

Comment: It does work, but you have to click it a few times, I will check though

Comment: The class gets removed and it closes but it's like there is a lag

Comment: It's because of the `max-height: 1000px`.  You need to tinker with that number because it is starting the transition from `1000px` and your example is only 100px.  Try setting your max-height lower.

Comment: Only the actual website it's on (link above) - it's actually a lightweight WP plugin

I have only used a tinyurl instead of the actual site because in the past I found them appear in search results.

The other thing I was thinking was the height may vary greatly so I'm not sure best how to handle the transition timing.

Wold JS be better for that?

I could try and recreate it, the structure seems fairly straightforward

Comment: I have tried to make a codepen here 

https://codepen.io/shereewalker/pen/gOXEdwg

I think i need to add Vanilla JS to it though - I can't work out how!

Comment: Hmmm my content volume varies hugely so I'm not sure this approach will work then?

Comment: As I mentioned, it's a hacky workaround and is not ideal.  There is no "good" solution for animating a `height: auto` that I have ever found.

Comment: I don't suppose you know how I could achieve this in JS?